# How to get the specific string value from an output?

Tags: php, string, web-scraping, substring, substr

here is the echo:

```
echo substr($price2->plaintext,0);
```

output::

```
**4,629.00**33.1579.00152.10126.75549.00829.01999.00779.00779.00899.001,660.001,249.00
```

I want only the bold part as the output that is **4.629.00**

Comment: What's the logic?

Comment: And you want to replace `,` with `.` or is that a typo?

Comment: it is typo @brombeer. i just want first value